# show listview for Arraylist from another Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

i want to make local HighScore table and show it in the main Activity lets say.
ive build an `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter` and etc.
When i am open the intent that contains the list view i dont see the list view i get some location in the app code as a text view.(See The Picture)

[image]

code:
**Person** class that has the `Arraylist`

```
public class Person extends Activity {
    EditText name;
    Button ok;
    TextView enter;
    Integer Score;
    String Name;
    Person person;
    ArrayList<Person> TopTen = new ArrayList<Person>(10);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_person);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Score = intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0);//defualt value if thers no score
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namep);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        enter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entername);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lets see if you are can be on TopTen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        person = new Person();
        person.Name = name.getText().toString();
        person.Score = Score;
        ok.setOnClickListener(SendActionListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener SendActionListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // error is here
            /*Person lastEntry = TopTen.get(TopTen.size()-1);//Last element of the arraylist
            Log.d("TopTen", lastEntry.Score.toString());
            if(lastEntry.Score < Score){//checking score
                lastEntry.Score = Score;//put score aka Value
                lastEntry.Name=name.getText().toString();//put name aka Key
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are now on the TopTen List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }*/
            /*Iterator<Person> iterator = TopTen.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                if(!iterator.hasNext()){//last value of the list

                }

            }*/
            int size = TopTen.size() - 1;
            Log.d("size", String.valueOf(size));
            if (size == -1) {//No Values in the array
                TopTen.add(person);
            } else {
                size = TopTen.size() - 1;
                if (person.Score > 0) {
                    if (TopTen.get(size).Score < person.Score) {
                        TopTen.remove(size);
                        TopTen.add(person);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are in topten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Person.this, MainActivity.class);
                        //intent.putExtra("ArrayList", TopTen);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not in topten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Person.this, MainActivity.class);
                        //intent.putExtra("ArrayList", TopTen);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Collections.sort(TopTen, new ScoreComparator());
        }
    };

    public Integer getScore() {
        return Score;
    }

    class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return person1.getScore().compareTo(person2.getScore());
        }

    }

}//end of Person
```

**TopTen** class that contain the `list view`

```
public class TopTen extends ListActivity {
    Person p;
    Person a;
    Person b;
    Person c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_topten);
        p = new Person();
        /*a = new Person();
        b = new Person();
        c = new Person();

        a.Name="Daniel";
        a.Score=20;
        b.Name="Zohar";
        b.Score=15;
        c.Name="Yakir";
        c.Score=10;

        p.TopTen.add(a);
        p. TopTen.add(b);
        p. TopTen.add(c);*/
        Log.d("inside", "TopTen OnCreat");
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d("inside", "populateListView");
        ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.activity_topten, R.id.text1, p.TopTen);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Topten_activity** xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_orange"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:text="@string/topten"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: never reference an activity in an Adapter. You have to pass Your TopTen ArrayList in another way.

Comment: Clearly what you should do to fix this bug is do an Android Tutorial that explains to you how Android works in general such as this guy's videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXsw and once you know how **not to instantiate Activities by hand**, and *have dedicated classes to store data that you display rather than merge your "Person" (data) with the Activity (display of data)*, and most importantly **when you know what you are doing**, you should clean out what you've written and re-do it.

Comment: will re do it as fast as i can

Answer (score 0):

Pass your list array as parseable bundle or simply object list from one activity to second

Comment: While that is true, the real problem here is that his "list array" consists of Activities.